# Unrecognized Guid format error while Installing WFFM Module in Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8

I have recently upgraded Sitecore from 6.6 version to 8.0 update -4. 
And started upgrading WFFM module but I was getting some error related with analytics.
So I planned to install fresh WFFM 8.0 module in Sitecore, while installing it's throwing an error **"Unrecognized Guid format"**.
I already tried with removing ItemNameValidation setting in web.config file. But still not working for me.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was another issue with upgrading and `Unrecognized Guid format` error.

Check this link if it helps: [Sitecore LinkDatabase throws System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format](http://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/26/sitecore-linkdatabase-unrecognized-guid-format/).

You just need to add an .aspx page from the bottom of this page to your website folder and check if there are any items with broken Tracking field.

If there are any, you open them in Content Editor, click Goals, click Attributes. And that's it.

Comment: Thanks @Marek I'll try this thank you very much for help

Comment: I didn't try this one easy solution worked for me after disabled Sitecore.Analytics.config and remove value from Item Name Validation setting, it's installed successfully.